# LINQ System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Хочу сделать следующее:

```
var servers = db.Servers.Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Server_id,
                    ConnectionString = GetConnectionString(x.ServerIp, x.DbName)
                }).ToList();
```

В ответ получаю:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.String GetConnectionString(System.String, System.String)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Неужели внутри запроса нельзя вызывать вспомогательный метод?

Comment: Ну так опубликуйте его ответом!

Answer (score 1):

Решение я нашел... Сначала нужно выбрать в List, а потом в этом листе нужно сделать еще один Select, но теперь можно использовать самописные методы

Answer (score 1):

Внутри **LINQ to Entities** можно вызывать пользовательские функции, но для этого необходимо создать эту функцию в базе данных или XML-файле с такими же параметрами, на свою функцию и пометить атрибутом [EdmFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.metadata.edm.edmfunction(v=vs.110).aspx). Это связано с тем, что **Entity Framework** пытается преобразовать ваш запрос в **SQL** и встречает незнакомую конструкцию, с которой он не знает как работать.

В качестве примера, можно использовать следующую статью на MSDN: ["Как вызывать функции, определяемые в модели, в качестве методов объекта"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd456845(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Насчет вашего решения

> Сначала нужно выбрать в List, а потом в этом листе нужно сделать еще один Select, но теперь можно использовать самописные методы

Не является эффективным, потому что объекты, вместе со всеми зависимыми коллекциями, будут выгружаться в память. Лучше всего сделать начальный маппинг на уровне БД и уже потом потом производить операции с меньшим объемом данных.

```
db.Servers.Select(x => new { x.Server_id, x.ServerIp, x.DbName })
          .AsEnumerable()
          .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.Server_id,
                    ConnectionString = GetConnectionString(x.ServerIp, x.DbName)
                });
```